# I am getting npm errors in ubuntu 16.04 when I run npm start

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, ubuntu, npm

I have node v7.10.1 and npm  v4.2.0 installed on my ubuntu 16.04 os. When I run start npm or sudo start npm I get the below error. It was working this morning now I am getting errors. Please assist

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.10.0-32-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v7.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! path /home/dombo/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'/home/dombo/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ' 
/home/dombo/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/dombo/.npm/_logs/2017-08-18T20_04_33_148Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Yes it gives me another error  --  npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/dombo/package.json'

Comment: You need to `cd` to a directory containing a node project (with a `package.json` file) before you run `npm start`

Comment: thank you, my mistake was in a wrong folder

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that npm can't find your package.json. Be sure that file exists, and you are in the same directory before running `npm start`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `/home/dombo/package.json` file exists. It is possible that you are in the wrong directory.